# Authentication URL responded with an illegal response code error in ADF

Tags: web-services, authentication, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-adf-mobile

I am trying to create an authentication in ADF mobile where the login URL is the peoplesoft login page. When i give in the username and password in the emulator, it throws an error.\

```
Terminating
Authentication URL responded with an illegal response code.
It is not basic authentication end point.
Please contact administrator
```

I have followed the following tutorial

```
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/accessing_secure_web_services_from
```

Here instead of creating a remote secured login server, I want to use peoplesoft to authenticate.Any Ideas?

I have also seen somewhere that you can authenticate each web service you call by adding the username and password in the SOAP header. Any tutorials for ADF would be much appreciated and @Shay Shmeltzer any ideas would be helpful
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oracle MAF only supports security authentication against HTTP Basic Authentication pages, so I don't think you can use peoplesoft login page to authenticate neither your application nor you web services.

Otherwise you can create a secure ADF page the validates login through peoplesoft login credentials(username-password) then deploy that page to a server and secure your MAF application using that page.

Some useful links 
[Accessing Secure Web Services from ADF Mobile](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/accessing_secure_web_services_from)
[ADF Mobile - Secured Web Service Access](http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2012/11/adf-mobile-secured-web-service-access.html)
[ADF Mobile Application Security](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/doc.111230/e24475/security.htm)

And about your second question yes you can customize the envelop header being send from MAF application to a soap webservice (add username and password or any other attributes) by extending the `SOAPProvider` class and add it to the datacontrol.dcx file as the provider for the webservice.

The only example I can find online
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/doc.111240/e24475/amxwebservices.htm#autoId3